# Java: Add element into a list inside a HashMap

Tags: java, performance, list, dictionary

I was wondering if there were a more efficient way to add an element into a list inside a hashmap instead of making a copy of the list, adding the element to the copylist and then make a put inside the map with the specific key associated to the list to overwrite that map part location...

```
Map <Integer, List<Object>> myMap = new HashMap <Integer, List<Object>>();


....add function

List <Object> tmp = new LinkedList();
if (myMap.containsKey(myListKey.hashCode())) { //keycheck
    tmp = myMap.get(myListKey.hashCode());     //copy
    tmp.add(myObjectToAdd);                    //add
    myMap.put(myListKey.hashCode(), tmp);      //overwrite
}
```

I tried several ways to get direct access to the inner list but the compiler seems on her/its period today...

Comment: Why are you using the `hashCode()` as the key? That's just *asking* for trouble. And what makes you think your current code is *copying* a list at all? It's just fetching a reference. (You don't need the `put` at the end...) Time to learn more about hash codes and references, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

First, there's no reason you should be calling `hashCode()` for putting items into the list. For one thing, distinct keys can have the same hash code, which will result in behavior you likely don't want. Just use the keys themselves as the keys. A `HashMap` will internally use the key's hash code to efficiently do the get/put operations.

Your add function should look more like this:

```
Map<ListKeyType, List<Object>> myMap = ...

... add function

List<Object> tmp = myMap.get(myListKey);
if (tmp == null) {
    tmp = new LinkedList<Object>();
    myMap.put(myListKey, tmp);
}
tmp.add(myObjectToAdd);
```

That way, you only create a new list when the map does not contain the key.

Comment: @almasshaikh - It will not throw a null pointer exception, because if `tmp` is `null`, it is assigned a non-`null` value before it is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ted Hopp's solution, which works perfectly fine, or use Guava's [ListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html), like that:

```
ListMultimap<ListKeyType,Object> myMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

...add function

myMap.put(myListKey, myObjectToAdd);
```

I would pick Ted's answer, just adding this answer for another option.

Moreover, compilers "on their period" love Guava!